# Django Model Struct within a Struct?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, structure

I'm trying to create a structure within a structure under Django's models.py. I know how to do this in C but am new to python.

For example, I have a class:

```
class OneDay(models.Model)
hour1 = ?
hour2 = ?
...
hour23 = ?
hour24 = ?
```

Each hour will have a list of identical properties. I want to apply these properties to every single hour within the OneDay class. I don't believe they are ForeignKeys.

```
class PeriodProperties(models.Model)
isX = boolean
isY = boolean
isZ = boolean
R = number
P = number
```

So with this I would be able to look up:

```
hour5.isX == false?
hour10.R > 50%?
```

Something like that. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Basically, you make:

```
class OneDay(models.Model)
    hour1 = models.ForeignKey("PeriodProperties", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="hour1s")
    ...
```

Then you could do something like:

```
oneDay.hour1.isX
```